# p:remoteCommand run on page load instead of button's onclick event in javascript

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, remotecommand

I have to call a remote command through javascript. The remote command is working fine but it invokes on page load instead of the button's onclick event.

Following is my xhtml file code as well as the bean code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">

<h:head>
    <title>Crowd Flow</title>
</h:head>

<f:event listener="#{task.loadTaskByTaskId(param['task_id'])}"
    type="preRenderView" />

<h:body bgcolor="white">

    <h:outputScript>
        function getCurrentLocation() {
            testingCommand();           
        }
    </h:outputScript>

    <h:panelGroup id="header" layout="block">
        <h3>Welcome to the task.</h3>
    </h:panelGroup>


    <h:panelGroup id="taskLayout" layout="block">
        <h:outputText value="Category is #{task.taskCategory}"></h:outputText>
        <h:outputText value="Task id is is #{task.id}"></h:outputText>

        <c:if test="#{param['task_id']=='9'}">
            <h:form style="width:400px;" id="newTagTaskForm">

                <p:remoteCommand name="testingCommand"
                        actionListener="#{task.testingCommand()}" autoRun="false" />

                Task Name : <h:outputText id="taskName"
                    value="#{task.newPlaceTagTask.name}"></h:outputText>
                <br />
                Task Description : <h:outputText id="taskDescription"
                    value="#{task.newPlaceTagTask.description}"></h:outputText>
                <br />
                Address : <h:outputText id="taskAddress"
                    value="#{task.newPlaceTagTask.location.address}"></h:outputText>
                <br />
                Image : <h:graphicImage width="50" height="50"
                    url="#{task.newPlaceTagTask.location.image}" />
                <br />
                <h:inputHidden value="#{task.userId}" id="taskPlaceTagUserId"
                    name="taskPlaceTagUserId" />

                <h:inputHidden value="#{task.newPlaceTagTask.location.id}"
                    id="taskPlaceTagLocationId" name="taskPlaceTagLocationId" />

                <h:commandButton id="testing" value="submit" type="submit" onclick="getCurrentLocation();return false;" ></h:commandButton>
            </h:form>
        </c:if>
    </h:panelGroup>
</h:body>
</html>
```

Here is the bean function, bean is view scoped.

```
package com.project.crowdsource.beans;

import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;

@ManagedBean(name="task")
@ViewScoped

public class TaskBean implements Serializable {
    public TaskBean() {
        //initiating user's data access object.
        taskDao = new TaskDAO();
    }

    public String testingCommand() {
        System.out.println("in action testing command");

        return "";
    }   
}
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: How did you install PrimeFaces? Didn't you see any warning like *"Warning: This page calls for XML namespace declared with prefix p but no taglibrary exists for that namespace"* in IDE?

Comment: @BalusC: I've had several moments where the PF jar was not loaded correctly but there was no error like you describe. What happened was that the EL (no () at the method name) was executed as **value expression on page load** while it was in the action of a p:commandButton. All kinds of unexpected errors, but NOT the one you describe. In this case it could still be called as a method expression, but at the wrong/unexpected moment. (I was enhancing PF so I created the jar myself each time). So I think the OP should clean the deploy folder on the server, restart en deploy again.

Comment: And as I experienced myself, multiple times there is a 3. When autodeploy of a webapp was enabled with a 'hot'/'live/workspace' dependency on a PrimeFaces jar I was also working on (maven, jboss ide). So in this case, no upvote on the comment from me ;-)